# Android Remove items from ArrayList<List<String>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to remove items from the Arraylist?

```
final ArrayList<List<String>> finalArrayList = null;
buf="1,2,3,four,5,six,nine,10";
finalArrayList.add(Arrays.asList(buf.split(",")));
   for(int i = finalArrayList .size()-1 ; i >0; i--){
      for(int i1 = finalArrayList .get(i) .size()-1 ; i1 > 0; i1--){
         if(isNumeric(finalArrayList.get(i).get(i1))==true){
            Log.d("arra", finalArrayList.get(i).get(i1).toString());
            finalArrayList.remove(finalArrayList.get(i).get(i1));
         }
     }
  }
}
```

It would also be great if someone link to declaration and explanation tuts.

**I don't know its legal or not,but it worked.Thanks to**  [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TaZbcXkpxs) and [this links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java).

```
final ArrayList<List<String>> finalArrayList = null;
String[] strn = buf.split(",");
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String> ();

for(int i =0;i< strn.length;i++){
names.add(strn[i]);
//System.out.println(names);
}
Iterator<String> i = names.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
String s = i.next();
//System.out.println("Printing>>>" + s);
try{
    if(isNumeric(s)==true){
        System.out.println("Removing...");
        i.remove();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No numeric");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("On Removing Error===>" +  e.getMessage());
}
}
finalArrayList.add(names);
```

Comment: If you remove items while iterating (without precaution), you will end up with exception or an unwanted result :)

Comment: BING0.

OK.how to remove if you don't mind to tell.

Answer (score 2):

```
 finalArrayList.remove(finalArrayList.get(i).get(i1));
```

Here `finalArrayList.get(i).get(i1)` will give you `String` at `i1th` position of `list` which is there at `ith` position in `finalArrayList`

You are trying to remove `String` from `ArrayList` of `List<String>` you need to do something like this *(Well not sure you want to remove it or not)*

```
(finalArrayList.get(i)).remove(i1);
```

Comment: `(finalArrayList.get(i)).remove(i1);` is  giving a null error.