# BufferedReader not null yet .readLine() returning null

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedreader

I have a weird problem, where my code seems fine (for me at least), yet on the debugger and actual result is always wrong.

Firstly the code:

```java
private void updateRegistry( String filename ){
    BufferedReader database = Init.MANAGER.readFile( Path.getDB(), filename );

    REGISTRY.clear();

    long maxLines = database.lines().count();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
        try {
            String currentLine = database.readLine();
            Registry regAdd = new Entry( currentLine );
            REGISTRY.add( regAdd );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( ERROR.getStackTrace( e ) );
        }
    }
}
```

So, all `currentLine` variables in the loop always returns `null`.

Being the `REGISTRY` a constant on the class which is a `LinkedList`.
And `ERROR` another constant to report errors, which is not relevant.

I'm aware of `.readLine()` that reads a line per method call, making each call the next line to be read.

**Also, by using the debugger, I can confirm the data is being recovered in the `BufferedReader` variable.**

Yet the `.readLine()` method returns null. I have no idea what the problem is.

My only guess is the `.lines()` that I used to count them. Does that make the stream null? If this is the problem, how can I correct it, since I need the line count.

What am I doing wrong? I debugged this a hundred times, nothing I do gives me the data.

### EDIT:

<s>For future reference, I used the example of this other post, which I prefer more than the while loop. After removing the `.lines()` variable and the loop</s>

```
private void updateRegistry( String filename ){
    BufferedReader database = Init.MANAGER.readFile( Path.getDB(), filename );

    REGISTRY.clear();

    try {
        for ( String currentLine = database.readLine(); currentLine != null; currentLine = database.readLine() ) {
            Registry regAdd = new Registry( currentLine );
            REGISTRY.add( regAdd );
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        System.err.println( ERROR.getStackTrace( e ) );
    }
}
```

**[Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706141/3662739)**

Thanks for the help, now I can finish my work assignment faster! xD

As, now my best friend, [Holger mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32968091/3662739), gonna use the stream loop directly, which makes it even neater.

`database.lines().forEach(currentLine -> REGISTRY.add(new Entry(currentLine)));`

And an one liner! Beautiful! Gonna dwelve on the stream world after this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`BufferedReader.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--):

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

Thus, after invoking `long maxLines = database.lines().count();`, there is no guaranty that you can read any lines from the same reader afterwards. In typical implementations, this operation consumes all lines.

If you can’t re-acquire an equivalent reader, but really need the count beforehand, the only option is to buffer them, e.g. to collect all lines into a `List` like

```
List<String> list=database.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to get the size and the contents.

---

If you don’t need the count beforehand, you can replace the counting operation with your actual operation:

```
database.lines().forEach(currentLine -> REGISTRY.add(new Entry(currentLine));
```

As [danmec has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32968172/2711488), even without the stream API, you don’t need the count beforehand, when all you want to do with it, is performing the iteration.

Comment: Like I thought it was the .lines() method. Thank you for the haste.

Comment: Oh, I saw the edit now, right. That makes it even cleaner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

[`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) is a new method in Java 8 which I'm not too familiar with. However, since you just want to process each line in turn, you would typically use something like this:

```
String currentLine = null;
while ((currentLine = database.readLine()) != null) {
    // do processing
}
```

Comment: Right, I understand the concept of making the assignment a condition, that never occured to me. Thanks for the quick response.