# How to upload a large file into GCP Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have 3GB of size data file to upload into GCP Cloud Storage. I tried with the example in GCP Uploading objects tutorial. But when I'm trying to upload I got the following error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Required array size too large
```

I tried as follows,

```
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(gcpBucketName, "ft/"+file.getName());
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.get().create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())));
return blob.exists();
```

How may I fix this? Are there any possible way to upload large files using GCP Cloud storage java client?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Version of storage:

```
  <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
  <version>1.63.0</version>
```

Preparation:

```
            BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, date.format(BASIC_ISO_DATE) + "/" + prefix + "/" + file.getName());
            BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("application/gzip").build();
            uploadToStorage(storage, file, blobInfo);
```

Main method:

```
private void uploadToStorage(Storage storage, File uploadFrom, BlobInfo blobInfo) throws IOException {
    // For small files:
    if (uploadFrom.length() < 1_000_000) {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(uploadFrom.toPath());
        storage.create(blobInfo, bytes);
        return;
    }

    // For big files:
    // When content is not available or large (1MB or more) it is recommended to write it in chunks via the blob's channel writer.
    try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10_240];
        try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(uploadFrom.toPath())) {
            int limit;
            while ((limit = input.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, limit));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Examples in GC Storage GIT https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/StorageSnippets.java

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This solution is exakt what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the array that is returned by **Files.readAllBytes** has a [bigger size than the maximum allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43782586/8935548).

A workaround you can do is to divide the file into multiple arrays of bytes, upload them as separated files to the bucket and join them using the [gsutil compose command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose).